# Adding S&P 500 curve to Brock value

Tags: r, quantmod

I have the following code for plotting Brock value

```
require(quantmod)

# Pull S&P500 from Yahoo
getSymbols("^GSPC", src="yahoo", from="1947-01-01")
# Convert to monthly, since GDP/AAA are quarterly/monthly, respectively
SPX <- to.monthly(GSPC, name="SPX")

# Pull GDP and AAA bond yield from FRED
getSymbols("AAA;GDP", src="FRED")
# Convert xts index to yearmon, so series will merge cleanly
index(AAA) <- as.yearmon(index(AAA))
index(GDP) <- as.yearmon(index(GDP))

# Merge, fill w/NA, and omit all obs where we don't have data for all 3 series
x <- na.omit(merge(SPX, GDP, AAA, fill=na.locf))
indexTZ(x) <- "UTC"  # avoid potential timezone issues with non-datetime index

# Calculate Brock Value
x$BV <- x$GDP/(2*x$AAA)
# plot
plot(log(x[,c("SPX.Close","BV")]), main="Brock Value")
```

The above code produces following plot:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is superimpose a S&P 500 curve on the plot like it is shown on this figure:

[image]

How would this be possible?

Comment: After that plot command, use `lines` to add the second line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Your Plot
plot(index(x), log(x[,"SPX.Close"]), 
     main= "Log Brock Value and Log S&P Close", col = "black",
     ylab = "Log Value", xlab = "Years", type = "l")
lines(index(x), log(x[,c("BV")]), col = "red")
legend('bottomright', c("SPX.Close","Brock"), 
       lty=1, col=c('black', 'red'), bty='n', cex=1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Would challenge you to get recession bars for the base plot using FRED data. See [here](http://nakisa.org/bankr-useful-financial-r-snippets/recession-shading/) and [here](http://earlh.com/blog/2009/08/11/shading-pieces-of-an-r-plot/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `ggplot2` solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

g1 <- ggplot(data=x, aes(x=Index, y=log(BV), color='Brock')) + geom_line() + 
      geom_line(aes(x=Index, y=log(SPX.Close), color='SPX')) + scale_x_yearmon() +
      labs(x='Date', y='Log10(Value)') + ggtitle('Brock Value') + 
      scale_colour_manual(name="Value", values=c(Brock="black", SPX="indianred"))
g1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Any way to get rid of the 'gen'?

Comment: I'm sure you can, but I don't know how (or better, I don't know yet: I'm quite new to ggplot2). I'll do some trials and let you know!